# Creating a list of students and assigning a function to each button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am trying to allow clients to create a list of students then view more info by simply clicking on the button with the students name. I've got it to create the button and display the students name in the button but it only calls the function when I click submit to add the student to the list, the actual student button doesn't seem to function.

```
function updateStudentList() {
    var html = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        html += "<li><button type='button' class='studentButton'" + "id=" + students[i].name +">" + students[i].name + "</button></li>";
    }

    $('#studentList').html(html);

    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(students[i].name).addEventListener('click', openStudentInfo(students[i].name));
    }
}

function openStudentInfo(studentName) {
    console.log("Opening " + studentName + " info.");

    var studentInfo = requestStudentByName(studentName);

    if (studentInfo != null) {
        var studentInfoForm = $("#studentInfoForm");
        var html = "";

        html += "<h3>Student Name: " + studentInfo.name + "</h3>";
        html += "<h3>Student ID: " + studentInfo.studentID + "</h3>";

        studentInfoForm.html(html);

        $("#studentInfoModal").show();
    } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="studentList"> </ul>
```

Note: I can't use the onclick tag in HTML, it causes security issues. Cordova also blocks this.

Comment: Event delegation is what you are looking for

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript _and_ jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you binding the event is not ok. Try binding this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#studentList").on("click", ".studentButton", function() {
        var studentId = $(this).data("studentid");
        openStudentInfo(studentId);
    });
});
```

And in your HTML generation:

```
html += "<li><button type='button' class='studentButton' data-studentid='" + students[i].studentID +"'>" + students[i].name + "</button></li>";
```

This kind of event delagation works not metter how you create the elements inside the root element(`studentList` in this case), because the event was bound in it, and not on the dynamic elements.

Comment: Thank you, this had solved my issue. Never knew I could have bound the event to the list itself.

Comment: @SebastianMaj it is a good practice even if the elements are not created dynamicaly. By doind that, you have just one event in bound in the dom - in the list - and not in **N** events for each list item of your list.

Answer (score 1):

no jquery version of DontVoteMeDown's answer

```
document.getElementById('studentList').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clickedEl = event.target;
    if(clickedEl.className === 'studentButton') {
        var studentId = clickedEl.dataset.studentId;
        openStudentInfo(studentId);
    }
});
```